# How to use generated token from passport Laravel oAuth

Tags: laravel, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport

Can someone assist me here, i have succeeded in setting up my passport on laravel 5.4 everything seems to work perfected. My question is once token is generated, am i supposed to save it for subsequent usage? i am just confused on the workflow. I am using password grant. I want to know how to pass token to another route that is making another call to another endpoint once token has been generated.

Comment: If possible go through https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5-3/episodes/13 this video tutorial by @Taylor Otwell

Answer (score 0):

You append the token generated for each and every subsequent request that needs to be authenticated.In this case attach to the Authorization header of the request. Something like this:

Bearer eJ0eXAiOi.......